# How to store configuration variables in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

M'y script's variables are  currently stored in a php File as an array. I want to store them in mysql database, however I don't if I should store them as rows or columns. If I use columns it would be easier to retrieve them (only one query), but if I have too many variables the page would have to scroll horizontally and I think it would be hard to find data in phpmyAdmin. If I use rows then how would I retrieve all of them using a single query and store them in the $config array?

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Unless it's user-configuration settings, or changes every couple of days, it does not belong into the database. That's a redundant extra query for each page invocation.

Comment: So the admin can change things like URL title keywords directly from the admin panel  without having to open the php file.

Comment: Well you can use an `.ini` file for that. Reading and rewriting them is as simple. Or did you just want to refer them to phpMyAdmin to avoid the coding overhead of an admin panel for a config settings file? (Shameless plug: http://milki.include-once.org/genericplugins/genconfig.html)

Comment: Storing them in database would simplify changing some basic variables. Something like the wordpress settings.

Comment: No difference to any other configuration store. (Except again that WP-style database config tables are inefficient at runtime. That's a widespread but unprofessional malpractice from the phpNuke era.)

Answer (score 5):

Create config table, with 2 columns

```
Name | Value
```

and select it with

```
SELECT * FROM config
```

so it will look like

```
Name     | Value
offline  | 1
message  | Hello guys! This is my custom message
```

to get them into $config, use

```
$result = (mysql_query("SELECT * FROM config"));
while($row = mysql_Fetch_assoc($result){
    $config[$result['Name']] = $result['Value'];
}
```

that's it!

Comment: How would I store them in an array. I need something like this $config["url"] would get something.com

Comment: Ok say I use $config["offline"] would that echo 1?

Comment: @Kbr: On the left from my answer, there is a tick - click it

Answer (score 1):

Depends.. Are the variables user-based? Do you need to search them? One way to store is in a serialized format (string data in a `text` field) -- this will suffice if you don't need to search the variables. Otherwise, just store one row per (user-)key-value combination.